# How to get failed Role with annotation @RolesAllowed with ContainerRequestContext?

Tags: java, quarkus

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext){

        switch (containerResponseContext.getStatus()) {
            case 403:
                // Print failed role from @RolesAllowed
```

I am using a ContainerResponseFilter and I want to print the role the user is lacking in case of a 403 status error. But honestly I have no idea if this is possible. The only thing I found is

```
final SecurityContext securityContext = containerRequestContext.getSecurityContext();
securityContext.isUserInRole("SomeRole")
```

But that does not help me either because I don't want to write all possible roles here.

Comment: How are you creating your Principal?  Is this using the built in Quarkus OIDC environment?  As part of my solution my `ContainerRequestFilter` creates a custom `Principal` and, for me, that Principal has a list of Roles.

Comment: Ok. And what property are you setting in the .yaml / .propertiers file. I found quarkus.oidc.roles.source = "Which value by the way ?"   . But in my case I would be specifically interested in the not authorised role. For example there is a @RolesAllowed("Manager") above an endpoint and I would need this role "Manager" in my filter . So I can print it out in a log .